# Solr CoreAware FilterFactory

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, solr, multicore

I need to write a custom solr FilterFactory which needs information about core against which it is registered (I assume multicore environment). For some reason I'm disallowed to implement SolrCoreAware from FilterFactory. Is it somehow possible to obtain the core from constructor/init method of the factory?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the ResourceLoader object:

```
@Override
public void inform(ResourceLoader loader) {
    Properties coreProperties = ((SolrResourceLoader) loader).getCoreProperties();
    System.out.println("SolrCoreName= " + coreProperties.getProperty("name"));
}
```

To get this working you need to set up the property on your solr.xml file:

```
<solr persistent="true" sharedLib="../lib">
    <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
        <core name="item" instanceDir="item">
            <property name="name" value="item" />
            <property name="dataDir" value="/data" />
        </core>
    </cores>
</solr>
```